# Can we change the XML structure of a file during file ingestion in MarkLogic using mlcp?

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I have a xml file to ingest in MarkLogic database where a new XML field has to be added .
And the requirement is to add that XML field only during the mlcp import.
Is this possible in MarkLogic using xquery?

XML file now -

```
<name>rashmita</name>
<employeeType>regular</employeeType>
```

XML to be changed -

```
<name>rashmita</name>
<employeeType>regular</employeeType>
<role>developer</role>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to modify the payload on ingest with MLCP.

[Transforming Content During Ingestion](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518)

> You can create an XQuery or Server-Side JavaScript function and install it on MarkLogic Server to transform and enrich content before inserting it into the database. Your function runs on MarkLogic Server.

[Function Signature](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_17741)

> A custom transformation is an XQuery function module that conforms to the following interface. Your function receives a single input document, described by $content, and can generate zero, one, or many output documents.

```
declare function yourNamespace:transform(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map)
as map:map*
```

So, for your example (assuming that the actual docs are well-formed XML) could look something like:

```
module namespace example = "http://marklogic.com/example";
declare function example:transform(
  $content as map:map,
  $context as map:map
) as map:map*
{
  let $doc := map:get($content, "value")
  let $root := $doc/*
  let $_ :=
    if ($root)
    then 
      map:put($content, "value", 
        document { element {$root/name()} {$root/@*, $root/*, <role>developer</role>} })
    else ()
  return $content
};
```

[Using a Custom Transformation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_36783)

> Once you install a custom transformation function on MarkLogic Server, you can apply it to your mlcp import or copy job using the following options:
>
> - **transform_module** - The path to the module containing your transformation. Required.
> - **transform_namespace** - The namespace of your transformation function. If omitted, no namespace is assumed.

An example invocation setting those parameters:

> mlcp.sh import -mode local -host mlhost -port 8000
> -username user -password password
> -input_file_path /space/mlcp-test/data
> -transform_module /example/mlcp-transform.xqy
> -transform_namespace "http://marklogic.com/example"

Comment: I have used this. It gives me this error . Any idea on why this gives me this endtag open error ? Is it because of the xml ? The error I gave below in the comment.

Comment: 23/01/11 09:35:52 ERROR contentpump.TransformWriter: Batch 83965077.0: Document failed permanently: /example/xml/employee.xml
23/01/11 09:35:52 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: <error:format-string xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting EndTagOpen_</error:format-string>

Comment: my example was incomplete. You would also need to declare the `example` namespace for that transform module. You can use any namespace and namespace-prefix, just need to be consistent in how it's declared and referenced (and the transform module has to have it declared - sorry about that!)

Comment: Not sure if you mean by this - xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-load("http://marklogic.com/example",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
      <uri>/example/xquery/addelement.xq</uri>
      <repair>none</repair>
      <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
    </options>)

Comment: I have added this xquery beforehand

Comment: And using this for mlcp -  import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -password ***** -input_file_path /example/xml -transform_module /example/xquery/addelement.xq -transform_namespace "http://marklogic.com/example"